# jquery - fade out all children except child being hovered

Tags: jquery, hover, parent-child, fade

Trying to do something fairly simple, but it's eluding me. I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="four">
                <div id="thumb1" class="suiting-thumb">
                    <img src="img/gallery/suit1-thumb.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                </div>


               <div id="thumb2" class="suiting-thumb">
                    <img src="img/gallery/suit2-thumb.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                </div>


               <div id="thumb3" class="suiting-thumb">
                    <img src="img/gallery/suit3-thumb.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                </div>
</div>
```

All I would like to do is "dim" the children of the parent div, EXCEPT for the child being hovered. I'm successfully doing so with this jQuery snippet, but there is a brief delay between the fade out / in:

```
$('.suiting-thumb').hover(function() {
                var thumbBtnIdPrefix = 'thumb';
                var thumbBtnNum = $(this).attr('id').substring((thumbBtnIdPrefix.length));
                $('.suiting-thumb:not(#thumb' + thumbBtnNum + ')').animate({
                    "opacity": .3
                }),200;             
            },
            function() {
                $('.suiting-thumb').animate({
                    "opacity": 1
            }),200;
        });
```

I feel as though I need to be fading out all the children of the parent div by selecting #four with my hover statement, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Any help would much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding new commands to the animation queue. You have to call `stop()` which stops all ongoing animations and immediately starts the new one.

```
$('.suiting-thumb').hover(function() {
    var thumbBtnIdPrefix = 'thumb';
    var thumbBtnNum = $(this).attr('id').substring((thumbBtnIdPrefix.length));
    $('.suiting-thumb:not(#thumb' + thumbBtnNum + ')').stop().animate({
        "opacity": .3
    }), 200;
}, function() {
    $('.suiting-thumb').stop().animate({
        "opacity": 1
    }), 200;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ywUUL/1/

Comment: Darth - are there any pros for using fadeTo() rather than animate()? Do you know if one is faster than the other? One thought I had was that fadeTo doesn't rely on the "opacity" which sometimes doesn't work in IE.

Comment: `fadeTo()` is only there for convenience, easier to remember maybe. jQuery normalizes access to css properties, so you don't have to worry about opacity under IE, it will do whatever it needs to do on non-standard browsers. It actually states in the docs that using `fadeTo` with a duration of 0 is the same as directly setting `.css('opacity', value)`.

Comment: How can you do the same thing, but then with imagebuttons?

Comment: @Rafael It should work with any markup, just change your selectors accordingly. What markup are you using as your "imagebuttons"?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.suiting-thumb').hover(function() {
                $('.suiting-thumb').not(this).animate({
                    "opacity": .3
                },200);

                $(this).animate({
                    "opacity": 1
                },200);
        });
```

This way the animations are executed in parallel. I've also optimized the selector somewhat to make it more readable and animate only the elements that need animation.

Note that you need to wait for a hover animation to finish before the next one starts. If you want that to be instant, make sure calling [$('.suiting-thumb').stop(true, false](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)) to stop all animations immediately and then start the next animation.